# MySQL - How to get counts of specific value from all the records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have course table and I am storing completion status of users with 'A'. Now I want to get how many `A` is available from `CompletionStatus` field for all records.

I want this result: `A` = 5.

### Course Table:

```
CourseRecordIdx     User    CompletionStatus 
---------------     ----    --------------------
1                   152     A___A_______________
2                   147     AA_______A__________
```

I have tried with `char_length` but getting count with underscore and I want to get only total of `A`:

```
SELECT char_length(CompletionStatus) FROM `course` where CourseRecordIdx = 36
```

Any idea how to get result with select query?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should change your database design. Are there just A's and underscores? Or are there also other grades like B etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this simplest way:

```
 SELECT length(REPLACE("field_name","_","")) FROM `tbl_name`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LENGTH` and `REPLACE` for that purpose :

```
SELECT LENGTH(CompletionStatus) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CompletionStatus, 'A', '')) as count_Char
 FROM `course`
```

This basically counts how many characters are in that string, and then checks the difference between that number, and the number of characters with out the specific character.

Comment: @saty I think you got confused a little bit, if the length os 13, and you have 4 'a' , then 13 -9(all except 'a') is 4.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following will work, first replace all `_` with `''`.
After that use `char_length()` function.

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(CompletionStatus,'_','') as totalA FROM course where CourseRecordIdx = 36;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this query for this:

```
SELECT CourseRecordIdx,User,CompletionStatus,
ROUND (   
    (
    LENGTH(CompletionStatus)- LENGTH( REPLACE ( CompletionStatus, "A", "")) 
    ) / LENGTH("A")) AS count    
from `course` where CourseRecordIdx = 36
```